# Laravel: How to get an array of existing ids from a column, where later on will use `whereIn`

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

consider the following function:

```
public function index($countryCode, Request $request) {
    $invalidCountryTranslations = $countriesTranslation->whereIn('LanguageID', $arrayOfExistingIds)->get();
    return view('admin.countriesTranslations.create', compact('countryCode', 'languages', 'countriesTranslation'));
}
```

I am using the above function to find out which countries are already in the table (so it wouldn't be called into the view) so basically `$arrayOfExistingIds` should hold those existing rows from `LanguageID` column.

so the question is, how do I get the existing arrays of a `LanguageID` column?

`$arrayOfExistingIds = ???`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck) method.

> The pluck method retrieves all of the values for a given key

```
Model::pluck('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

As Alexey told you, use `pluck()` method, it will retrieve a collection, if you want an array concatenate it with `toArray()` or with `all()` methods, just like this;

```
Model::take(5)->pluck("id")->toArray();
Model::take(5)->pluck("id")->all();
```

This will give you your desired array.
Try to not to use the `lists()` method because it is has been deprecated in 5.2.0.